# Using HTML pages in UIWebView, strange issues with relative page images but links work

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

So I'm creating an app which basically is a UIWebView that loads an HTML page, which should have images on it.  The HTML page is loading fine (confirmed with a little text on the page), but then I have this code in it:

```
<img src="images/image_1.png">
 <a href="images/image_1.png">test</a>
```

Check this out:

- The  tag has a broken image link
- But, when I tap on the  link, *the
  image loads!*

How is this happening?  What kind of solution is there?

I have the images in a subfolder of resources, which I added by "Create Folder References."

Help?  A note: This is on iPad, using 4.2.  But that shouldn't matter, right Apple?  (Also, changing it to xml <img /> type tag doesn't do anything)

Comment: Is the image really big?

Comment: The image is pretty big.  Is this a concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image was way too big - over 2500px wide.  Resizing to 1024px fixed it.  Thanks Jose Vega.

Also, Automator is a gift from the Gods when it comes to batch operations.